# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int' when using dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a basic [Vignere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher#Algebraic_description) encryption function for a single letter using user input, here's the code:

```
alphanumero = {0:'A', 1:'B', 2:'C', 3:'D', 4:'E', 5:'F', 6:'G', 7:'H',
8:'I', 9:'J', 10:'K', 11:'L', 12:'M', 13:'N', 14:'O', 15:'P', 16:'Q',
17:'R', 18:'S', 19:'T', 20:'U', 21:'V', 22:'W', 23:'X', 24:'Y', 25:'Z' }

inputlet = str(input("Enter letter to be encrypted: "))
try:
    print(alphanumero[inputlet])
except KeyError:
    letnum = [k for k, v in alphanumero.items() if v == inputlet[0]]
inputkey = str(input("Enter key letter: "))
try:
    print(alphanumero[inputkey])
except KeyError:
    keynum = [u for u, t in alphanumero.items() if t == inputkey[0]]
result = (letnum + keynum) % 26
print(result)
```

So when I try to run this, I want it to output `11` given `A` as the input letter and `L` as the input key, but instead I get this Error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'

So how can I fix this? I'm relatively new to Python so any answers are greatly appreciated

Comment: letnum and keynums are lists. you can't take the modulo of a list

Answer (score 1):

`letnum` and `keynum` are lists. `letnum + keynum` is the contatenation of the lists, it doesn't add the corresponding elements to each other. And you can't use `% 26` on a list. Use a list comprehension to combine them.

```
result = [(letter + key) % 26 for letter, key in zip(letnum, keynum)]
```